# I try to get the optimal number of topics in my corpus with LDA model but return to me a runtime error, how can I fix it?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, python, model

I have an runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
  0%|          | 0/29 [00:48<?, ?it/s]
```

When I try run this code (from the book "Text Analytics with Python: A Practitioner's Guide to Natural Language Processing", 2nd edition, by Dipanjan Sarkar):

```
def topic_model_coherence_generator (corpus, texts, dictionary, start_topic_count=2, end_topic_count=10, step=1, cpus=1):
    models=[]
    coherence_scores = []
    for topic_nums in tqdm(range(start_topic_count, end_topic_count+1, step)):
        lda_model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=bow_corpus, id2word=dictionary, chunksize=1740, alpha='auto', eta='auto',
                                   random_state=42, iterations=500, num_topics=topic_nums, passes=20, eval_every=None)

        cv_coherence_model_lda = gensim.models.CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, corpus=bow_corpus,
                                                      texts=norm_corpus_bigrams, dictionary=dictionary,
                                                      coherence='c_v')

        coherence_score= cv_coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
        coherence_scores.append(coherence_score)
        models.append(lda_model)
    return models, coherence_scores

lda_models, coherence_scores = topic_model_coherence_generator(corpus=bow_corpus,
                                                               texts=norm_corpus_bigrams,
                                                               dictionary= dictionary,
                                                               start_topic_count=2,
                                                               end_topic_count=30,
                                                               step=1, cpus=16)
```

That I want is obtain the optimal number of topics of my corpus for obtain then the topics and interpreting topic model results. I'm biologist so I don't know how can I fix it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi. Here we don't usually fix bugs. Have a look at [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to clarify 1. where you took this code from, 2. how are you executing the code, etc.

Comment: It is from a book of Natural Language that I studying for make relationship between papers research and for executing the code I use Pycharm.

Comment: Also, please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can run your code to and check that we also get the same problem. What's the operating system you're using? What's the version of Python?